# Make canvas follow camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make canvas UI object follow my camera. It works but I do not want the Y axis of the canvas object to get affected. That is, it should follow only in X and Z axis but Y should stay fixed. How do I do this?

I have tried doing

```
menuCanvas.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(currentPos.x, -30, currentPos.z), targetPosition, smoothFactor);
```

but it changes to some other axis completely.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SmoothCameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menuCanvas;
    public Camera FirstPersonCamera;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float smoothFactor = 0.5f;

    public float offsetRadius   = 0.3f;
    public float distanceToHead = 4;

    public void LateUpdate()
    {
        // make the UI always face towards the camera
        menuCanvas.transform.rotation = FirstPersonCamera.transform.rotation;

        var cameraCenter = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position + FirstPersonCamera.transform.forward * distanceToHead;

        var currentPos = menuCanvas.transform.position;

        // in which direction from the center?
        var direction = currentPos - cameraCenter;

        // target is in the same direction but offsetRadius
        // from the center
        var targetPosition = cameraCenter + direction.normalized * offsetRadius;

        // finally interpolate towards this position
        menuCanvas.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, targetPosition, smoothFactor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

menuCanvas.transform.position = new vector3 (cam.transform.position.x, menuCanvas.transform.position.y, cam.transform.position.z)

Comment: you should cache the returns of the properties `transform` and `position` ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `var menuTransform = menuCanvas.transform; var targetPosition = cam.transform.position; targetPosition.y = menuTransform.position.y; menuTransform.position = targetPosition;` this would be more efficient property access wise